# Desmontar um Pen-Drive USB via código

Tags: c#, .net

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para desmontar uma unidade removível(Pen-Drive) via código c#.

Comment: Se for pra um sistema baseado em Unix com Mono, deve ser a coisa mais fácil do mundo, só um comando Shell. Com Mono ou .NET pra Windows, acredito que deve ser necessário usar a API do Windows, que não é tão amigável. Quando chegar em casa vou atrás de uma solução, se até então ninguém tiver postado uma.

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo @Renan, estou tentando achar alguma que funcione só que está difícil. Obg :)

Comment: Dá uma olhada no source desse projeto: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13530/Eject-USB-disks-using-C

Comment: Consegui resolver @TiagoCésarOliveira . Obg pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir do Windows XP você pode utilizar o comando nativo `MOUNTVOL`. De acordo com sua documentação:

> Creates, deletes, or lists a volume mount point. `Mountvol` is a way to
>   link volumes without requiring a drive letter.

Traduzindo:

> Cria, exclui ou lista um volume de ponto de montagem. `Mountvol` é uma maneira de vincular volumes sem a necessidade de uma letra de unidade.

Utilizando o seu código como base, seria esta a chamada sem a necessidade de nenhum componente externo:

```
private static void EjectDrive(char driveLetter)
{
    ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo("mountvol.exe", driveLetter + ": /d");
    Process.Start(ps);
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou exatamente como o esperado! Sem a necessidade de componente externo. Testei aqui no Windows 7 e funcionou. Obg OnoSendai :)

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha funcionado, @Rsouza!

Answer (score 2):

De uma olhada neste link, estava tentando fazer a mesma solução e tinha achado estes modelo, porem não foi mais preciso, utilizei transmissão de arquivos via Dropbox, então abandonei o projeto.

quem sabe te da uma luz! :)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13530/Eject-USB-disks-using-C

Comment: Esse artigo já tinha dado uma olhada. Mas é mt complexo, acabei achando uma uma solução mais fácil :) Obg

Answer (score 2):

Então galera,
Consegui achar uma programa que faz isso.

http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html

Ae eu fiz dessa maneira.

```
private static void EjectDrive(char driveLetter)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo("RemoveDrive.exe", driveLetter + ":");
        Process.Start(ps);
    }
```

Junto com o esse RemoveDrive na raiz do programa.
Obg Galera.